# Problemas con Js,Ajax,Php y JSON necesito ayuda

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Todo me funciona bien hasta el `console.log(response)`, pero al realizar el `var info = JSON.parse(response);` en la consola del navegador me indica  un `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2` y no he podido resolverlo. Me darían una mano por favor?

```
 $('.add_product').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var producto = $(this).attr('product');
                                            
    //alert(producto); 

    var action = 'infoProducto';
    //alert(action);


     $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true, n
        data: {action:action,producto:producto}, 
       
    
        success: function(response){            
            console.log(response);
```

////esto muestra la consola del console.log(response);
{"codproducto":"14","descripcion":"jorge4"}

```
        if(response != 'error'){             
            
            
           var info = JSON.parse(response); 
         
                 
                console.log (info);

                                                       
                
               $('#producto_id').val(info.codproducto);
              $('.nameProducto').html(info.descripcion);
                console.log(info.codproducto);                   
                console.log(info.descripcion);
                
                
     $('.bodyModal').html('<form action="" method="post" name="form_add_product" id="form_add_product" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); sendDataProduct();">' + 
            '<h3><i class="fas fa-cubes" style="font-size: 45pt;"></i> <br> Agregar Producto</h3>' +
            '<h4 class="nameProducto">'+ info.descripcion +'</h4><br>' +
            '<input type="text" name="cantidad" id="txtCantidad" placeholder="Cantidad del Producto" required>' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="producto_id" id="producto_id" value=" '+ info.codproducto +' " required>' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="action" class="add_product"  value="addProduct" required>' +
            '<div class="alert alertAddProduct"></div>' +
            '<button type="submit" class="btn_new"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Agregar</button>' +
            '<a href="#" class="btn_ok closeModal" onclick="closeModal();"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i> Cerrar</a>' +
        '</form>');

        }

    },

        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
    }
    });

    $('.modal').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo completo no veo donde cierre el if

Comment: por lo que veo dice in position 2, estas devolviendo un arreglo? si es asi hay un problema con el arreglo, no estas devolviendo esa posicion por lo que no puede acceder

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta Saul, para completar lo que me solicitaste. Necesitas el ajax.php?

Comment: Cual es la posicion 2 Plus? No te entendi tu pregunta